# SQL query that will return multiple averages

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a mysql query that will return an array of averages.
I'll explain:

[image: My rating table]

As you can see from the picture, I have a web page that has a table with questions as rows, and usernames as columns. The idea is that you can rate each user on each question.
When submitted, it goes into a mysql table "ratings" and each record holds the user id, question id and the value (rating of 1 through 10).
What I want to do is, I want to have an admin view that, instead of being able to rate user, instead of each select box, it should simply display the average for each user, for each question.

I could've done it in php by simply doing a mysql query for each cell in this table, but that would mean a gazillion queries.
What I want, is one query that will return me a 2 dimensional array, where the first dimension key is the user ID, and the second dimension is the array with the averages themselves, with the key as question ID.

I can't even begin to think of how to accomplish it. A solution, or even a hint on what direction to look at, will be most definitely appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratings` (
  `rating_id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `rating_value` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rating_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

Comment: can we has teh codez?

Comment: Could you post your table structure, please?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratings` (
  `rating_id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `rating_value` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rating_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

Comment: You mean questions as columns and users as rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a 2-dimensional array directly from MySQL - however, you can prepare your data to do so in php.

The query could look somewhat like that:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  question_id,
  AVG(rating_value) AS average_rating
FROM ratings
GROUP BY user_id, question_id
ORDER BY user_id
```

Like this you should get a result as following:

```
user_id | question_id | average_rating
1       | 1           | 2.4
1       | 2           | 4.1
1       | 3           | 3.0
2       | 1           | 1.0
2       | 2           | 7.9
```

And so on. From here on I guess you can solve the problem with php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create relations for each question, then JOIN each of those relations, and finally do a GROUP BY, like this:

```
SELECT q1.userid, avg(q1.value) as q1avg, avg(q2.value) as q2avg, 
       avg(q3.value) as q3avg, avg(q4.value) as q4avg 
FROM
(SELECT userid, questionid, value FROM ratings WHERE questionid=1) q1
JOIN
(SELECT userid, questionid, value FROM ratings WHERE questionid=2) q2
ON q1.userid = q2.userid
JOIN
(SELECT userid, questionid, value FROM ratings WHERE questionid=3) q3
ON q1.userid = q3.userid
JOIN
(SELECT userid, questionid, value FROM ratings WHERE questionid=4) q4
ON q1.userid = q4.userid
GROUP BY q1.userid
```

Working Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbc8a/2

It will give you result in 2D format.